# Has a Serre fibration over a connected base isomorphic fibers?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Has a Serre fibration $f:E\to B$ with $B$ a connected space isomorphic fibers over different points of $B$?

If $f$ is a fiber bundle, then all fibers are isomorphic. Hence, a possible counterexample would be a Serre fibration which is not a fiber bundle. It would be nice, if someone could provide a counterexample where $E$ and $B$ are non-pathological spaces, e.g. CW complexes.

Comment: By isomorphic, do you mean homeomorphic?  If $X$ is a connected CW-complex, then $PX\rightarrow X$, where $PX$ is the path space, will only have homotopy equivalent fibers.

Comment: Yes, I mean homeomorphic, isomorphic in the category of topological spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not always. In a counterexample below most fibers are intervals, but the fiber over one point is a point.

[image: Fibration]

Fibers are always homotopy equivalent, though.